# Set dynamic options array to woocommerce_form_field using a global variable

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, field

I am trying to set an array of `options` argument to `woocommerce_form_field()` in WooCommerce.

Here is my code that add dynamically an array to `$GLOBALS`:

```
foreach($kekei as $goods=> $goodness) { 
    $balbal."'".[$goodness['shipping_code']] = $goodness['shipping_name'];              
}

$GLOBALS['hariharis'] = $balbal;
```

So I use it in  `options` argument in `woocommerce_form_field()`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'custom_shipping_radio_button', 20);
$domain = 'woocommerce';

if (  WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0] == targeted_shipping_method() ) :


echo '<tr class="delivery-radio"><th>' . __('Delivery options', $domain) . '</th><td>';

$chosen = WC()->session->get('chosen_delivery');
$chosen = empty($chosen) ? WC()->checkout->get_value('delivery') : $chosen;
$chosen = empty($chosen) ? 'regular' : $chosen;

// Add a custom checkbox field
woocommerce_form_field( 'radio_delivery', array(
    'type' => 'radio',
    'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
    /*
    'options' => array(
    'regular' => __('Regular', $domain),
    'premium' => __('Premium +'.wc_price(2.00), $domain),
    'big' => __('Big +'.wc_price(3.00), $domain),
    'small' => __('Big +'.wc_price(5.00), $domain),

    */
    'options' => $GLOBALS['hariharis'],
    'default' => $chosen,
), $chosen );

echo '</td></tr>';

endif;
}
```

So here I use the variable `$GLOBALS['hariharis']` to dynamically pass `options` argument  in `woocommerce_form_field()`, but I am getting this error:

> *"Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in "*.

What I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in this first code block:

```
foreach($kekei as $goods=> $goodness) { 
    $balbal."'".[$goodness['shipping_code']] = $goodness['shipping_name'];
}

$GLOBALS['hariharis'] = $balbal;
```

The variable `$balbal` need to be initialized as an empty array first. 
You are **not setting an array** of key/values pairs into `$GLOBALS['hariharis']`.

Replace it with:

```
// Initializing the variable
$balbal = array();

// Loop through your multidimensional array
foreach( $kekei as $g_key => $g_values ) { 
    // Set key/value pairs to the new array
    $balbal[ $g_values['shipping_code'] ] = $g_values['shipping_name'];
}

$GLOBALS['hariharis'] = (array) $balbal;
```

It should better work assuming that `$g_values['shipping_code']` and `$g_values['shipping_name']` exist and are not empty.

Comment: ok, thank you. I have fixed the code by following what you said and it worked. But when i clicked on the radio button, the code cannot pickup the radio value, why?

Comment: please see my related thread, thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57751221/trying-to-ajax-woocommerce-form-field-but-have-null-error-at-console-log